# is it possible to get the Numeric index of url hash?

Tags: jquery, url, hash

so I have some code that works but I know it's not the right way to do it. I know there has to be an easier way.

I have links that are as follows

```
<a href="#1">&nbsp;<strong class="active">1</strong></a>
<a href="#2">&nbsp;<strong class="active">2</strong></a>
<a href="#3">&nbsp;<strong class="active">3</strong></a>
<a href="#4">&nbsp;<strong class="active">4</strong></a>
```

each of those links activate tab content which works great so no problem there.

I need to be able to give people a link directly to say tab content 3. so I figured that I could use window.location.hash 
so I did the following.

```
  if ( window.location.hash ==="#1") {
      jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').addClass('hide');
      jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').eq(0).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).removeClass('active');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).eq(0).addClass('active');
}
 else if( window.location.hash ==="#2"){
  jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').addClass('hide');
      jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').eq(1).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).removeClass('active');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).eq(1).addClass('active');
     }

 else if( window.location.hash ==="#3"){
  jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').addClass('hide');
      jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').eq(2).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).removeClass('active');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).eq(2).addClass('active');
     }
 else if( window.location.hash ==="#4"){
  jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').addClass('hide');
      jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').eq(3).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).removeClass('active');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).eq(3).addClass('active');
     }
 else if( window.location.hash ==="#5"){
  jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').addClass('hide');
      jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').eq(4).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).removeClass('active');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).eq(4).addClass('active');
     }
 else if( window.location.hash ==="#6"){
  jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').addClass('hide');
      jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').eq(5).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).removeClass('active');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).eq(5).addClass('active');
     }
 else if( window.location.hash ==="#7"){
  jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').addClass('hide');
      jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').eq(6).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).removeClass('active');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).eq(6).addClass('active');
     }
 else if( window.location.hash ==="#8"){
  jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').addClass('hide');
      jQuery(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').eq(7).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).removeClass('active');
      jQuery( ".slidelinks li strong" ).eq(7).addClass('active');
     }
```

This works EXACTLY as it needs but it just seems too cumbersome.

is there a way to grab the index() of a hash? so say if it is #2, or #3 just use the index then I can use eq("whatever the index is").
I know what needs to happen just not sure what the syntax is.. I was also thinking I could grab the value of the hash and turn it into a numeric value, so if #2
an again I can use that in eq()

Comment: You've could built that code in 5, 6 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **all** your code with:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){ // DOM ready and $ alias secured

   // other DOM ready code here.........


   // Now, the 3 lines I promised earlier:
   var idx = window.location.hash.replace(/\D/g,'') - 1;
   $(".slides").find('.dslc-modules-area').addClass('hide').eq(idx).removeClass('hide');
   $(".slidelinks li strong").removeClass('active').eq(idx).addClass('active');



});
```

Also, you logic is quite odd. You don't need two classes `.hide` and `.show`. Only one. Think about it.

To recap, to get the index `0..n` you can use `window.location.hash.replace(/\D/g,'') - 1;` where `/\D/g` is a regex that replaces `g`lobally all `\D` non-digit characters occurrences  with `''` (so it removes them). So `"#1"` becomes `"1"-1` which is index `0`;

Comment: First off, thank you very much! am still learning. so you know :) and yea i thought i could just use hide (display none) but for some reason it wouldn;t show it back so I had to add  the show (display block)

Comment: what does /\D/g, do?

Comment: It's a regex that matches all non-digits in the string, and removes them by replacing them with `''`.

Comment: gotcha! would have never even known that! here's an interesting thing, if there is NO # in the url, it selects the last one by default, do I need to set the first one manually then?

Comment: @Deedub I miss your environment code to understand exactly what you're after, but out of the blue what you could try is: `var hash = window.location.hash || "1";` and than `var idx = hash.replace(/\D/g,'') - 1;` which, if no hash is present, will use index `0` by default.

Comment: no that's exactly right, basically set it to 0 if there is no hash.

Comment: @Deedub yep, untested but you got the idea.

Comment: very much so again, thanks so much. this works perfect. I can only think in psuedo code so far.. lol. Like I know what to "think" it's the language and prolly the logic that gets me... ha.

Comment: @Deedub all in time

Answer (score 0):

To parse the url location hash to a number, slice off the first character, and then parse/coerce to int using a unary `+` or `parseInt`.

```js
var hash = "#5";
var num = +hash.slice(1); // or parseInt(hash.slice(1), 10)

console.log(num);
```

Then you can generalize your code (and don't forget you can chain statements):

```
var hashNum = window.location.hash.slice(1) - 1;
jQuery(".slides .dslc-modules-area")
    .addClass('hide')
    .eq(hashNum).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
jQuery(".slidelinks li strong")
    .removeClass('active')
    .eq(hashNum).addClass('active');
```

Comment: That is brilliant! Thank you so much. since count starts at 0 and not one, it's one off, so how do I count down by one? ie if it's 1 it actually needs to be 0 to set the right one?

Comment: @Deedub Lol just subtract 1. JavaScript coerces strings to numbers when you use math operators (other than `+`) on them.

Comment: gotcha, very much appreciated!